# Name and/or generalization? "The slope of the secant through two points of a quadratic is the average of the slopes of the tangents at those points."

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections, tangent-line, slope, secant

Does the following property of quadratic equations have a name?  Is it generalized in some way? Or generalized to other functions?

> Pick any two points on the graph of any quadratic.  Draw a secant line through the points. Draw a tangent line through each of the points.  The slope of the secant line will equal the arithmetic average of the slopes of two tangent lines.

I have examined the wikipedia pages for quadratics and parabolas and there seems to be a lot of similar properties but (perhaps) not exactly this one. That is why I think it must be a specific case of something more general or maybe it is so obvious that it is not mentioned.  It seems to be related to the mean value theorem as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to a [well-known property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Axis_direction) of parabolas:

> The line parallel to the axis through the midpoint of a chord $AB$,
> also passes through the intersection of the tangents at $A$ and $B$.

As you can see in figure below, we have then:

$$
m_{AC}=-{y_A\over x},\quad
m_{BC}={y_B\over x},\quad
m_{AB}={y_B-y_A\over 2x}.
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Definitely on that wikipedia page but I would not have noticed it without your help.  Seems like it should be made more clear on that page.  A useful property definitely.

Comment: @LDinCT Another variation on the same theme is to notice that $AB$ is parallel to the tangent at the intersection of $MC$ with the parabola. This follows because, quoting the same [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Corollary_concerning_midpoints_and_endpoints_of_chords), "*if a parabola has several parallel chords, their midpoints all lie on a line parallel to the axis of symmetry*". But the slope of a tangent is the value of the derivative, and the derivative here is a linear function, so the slope at the midpoint is the average of the slopes at the endpoints.